# Ruby - including single module multiple times and ancestry hierarchy

Tags: ruby, inheritance, module

I'm reading 'Metaprogramming Ruby' right now and writing some code at the same time to clarify the concepts. I've read that when you include/prepend a single module multiple times, all further inclusions won't change the place of said module in the ancestry chain.

I wrote some code that works in a way that I did not expect - what actually happens there?

```
module GreatGrandfather; end

module Grandfather
  include GreatGrandfather
end

module Father
  include Grandfather
  prepend GreatGrandfather
end

module Son
  include Father
end

Son.ancestors # => [Son, Father, Grandfather, GreatGrandfather]
```

I've assumed that when I run `Son.ancestors`, Son would include Father, Father would include Grandfather and prepend GreatGrandfather and the ancestry tree would be set to `[Son, GreatGrandfather, Father, Grandfather]`. Obviously that didn't happen.

Once Son includes Father, it starts to look in the Father module and finds `include Grandfather` and `prepend GratGrandfather`. Does it actually 'go into' `Grandfather` where it includes GreatGrandfather, and only then executes the `prepend GreatGrandfather` line (and ignores it because it already exists in the ancestry)?

Truth be told, I doubt I will get much use out of it, but it won't hurt to know how exactly the modules 'chain' each other.

@edit - I've played around with it a bit more, and it doesn't seem that my intuition is right in either case. I've included a picture of the two ways I thought it could go, instruction after instruction, about creating the inheritance hierarchy - the one that appears to occur in the picture goes against the original example given, so neither #1 or #2 can be happening.

Modified example code (only GreatGrandfather changed)

```
module GreatGrandfather
  include Grandfather
end

module Grandfather
  include GreatGrandfather
end

module Father
  prepend GreatGrandfather
  include Grandfather
end

module Son
  include Father
end

Son.ancestors # => Son, GreatGrandfather, Father, Grandfather
```

[image]

in summary - I still have no idea how it happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Module#prepend_feature](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-prepend_features)

> Ruby’s default implementation is to overlay the constants, methods,
>   and module variables of this module to mod if this module has not
>   already been added to mod or one of its ancestors.

But you already add GreatGrandfather to Father through Grandfather.

This way it would work as you expect:

```
module GreatGrandfather; end

module Grandfather
  include GreatGrandfather
end

module Father
  prepend GreatGrandfather
  include Grandfather
end

module Son
  include Father
end

p Son.ancestors # => [Son, GreatGrandfather, Father, Grandfather]
```

**Update**

1.You cant modify example like this:

```
module GreatGrandfather
  include Grandfather
end

module Grandfather
  include GreatGrandfather
end
```

cause when you define GreatGrandfather Grandfather is not defined.

2.This is, what happens when you add modules to another modules. Comments illustrate, what happens with module hierarchy in time:

```
module GreatGrandfather
  # GG
end

module Grandfather
  # GG
  # G
  include GreatGrandfather
  # GG
  # G -> GG
end

module Father
  # GG
  # G -> GG
  # F
  prepend GreatGrandfather
  # GG
  # G -> GG
  # GG -> F
  include Grandfather
  # Don't change the position of GG in Father hierarchy, cause it is already in ancestors
  # GG
  # G -> GG
  # GG -> F -> G
end

module Son
  # GG
  # G -> GG
  # GG -> F -> G
  # S
  include Father
  # GG
  # G -> GG
  # GG -> F -> G
  # S -> GG -> F -> G
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, although to be honest it didn't clear much. I've added some more info info OP - could you weigh in?

Comment: Heh, I've actually just figured it out myself, as I've completely ignored that code within a module executes immediately. I've been playing with it in pry, so I missed it complaining about unitialized constant somehow - if I ran it in a file, the question would have a clear answer from the very beginning. Thank you!